# Meta.SE and downvote-based bans

Tags: discussion, voting, meta

On StackExchange sites, a downvote indicates a bad or non-useful question/answer. A user with many downvotes may receive a question-ban or answer-ban to encourage better contributions. This makes complete sense.

Conversely, votes on Meta sites are used to express agreement or disagreement over a question or answer. Downvotes may not indicate a bad contribution, just an unpopular opinion.

I just received the "in danger of being blocked" warning on this site, Meta.SE. I don't think I am a bad contributor by most standards. All my questions and answers have been well-received and deemed useful on the non-Meta sites.

The current behavior severely limits people from expressing unpopular ideas or issues. See the related question, ["That downvoted questions make you lose reputation limits diversity of opinion in Meta"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173020), which is similar but has a different focus.

This issue is very specific to Meta.SE, which is kind of a hybrid content+meta site. Is this something we want to consider? Should Meta.SE have different rules for bans because of the difference in context?

Comment: Note that Meta.SE is special and different; child-metas have no such ban.

Comment: Meta.SE **already** has a vastly adjusted ban algorithm. You are in no danger of triggering it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes exactly.. That's what I point out in my last para.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh hmm.. Why the warning then? I can see it even now.

Comment: The warning is based only on recent posts and on Meta.SE can be ignored, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks! Can you post an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm hoping to avoid another entry in my list of zero-answer unaccepted questions :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta.SE has already vastly lowered the thresholds at which you'll receive a post ban, and you certainly are not in any danger of receiving the ban. I've only ever seen 1 or 2 people running into the ban after quite deliberate trolling.

The warning you received is based entirely on your most recent posts and on Meta.SE can be ignored.