# Don't take rep for down votes on MSE

Tags: feature-request, meta

On MSE, down voting means I disagree, not "bad post." IMO, we don't want to punish users for writing potentially controversial ideas, so there should be no penalty for being downvoted. The other metas are already like this.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239491/meta-se-and-downvote-based-bans

Comment: Downvotes *don't* mean disagreement in the vast majority of posts here.

Comment: I vote on the merits of the post, not to punish users. When you reach 10 rep you can consider posting as Community Wiki, specially for feature requests that often come without research. I don't think voting should change.

Comment: @rene oh, very smart.

Comment: Agree. As a compromise step, making it -1 instead of -2 in this meta. Or disabling rep for this meta site as it works in other meta sites

Answer (score 4):

I think the current voting and reputation system does a good job of gauging community consensus on issues.

Even potentially controversial ideas can usually be written in a neutral way that simply introduces the issue and leaves answers from others (or you) to attract up/down votes on the for/against cases as appropriate.